# Diferencia entre Public Virtual y List<>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Hola gente me gustaria poder entender cual es la diferencia entre declarar una relacion de modelos (entity framework) mediante `public List<Modelo> Modelos { get; set; }` y `public Virtual Modelo Modelos { get; set; }`.
Desde ya gracias.

Comment: En este link lo puede revisar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542864/why-use-virtual-for-class-properties-in-entity-framework-model-definitions

Comment: En el segundo caso queres decir public virtual List<Modelo> Modelos {get;set;} ?

Comment: @DanielVorph es un link a SO en inglés, aquí tratamos de responder en español. si quieres puedes traducir la respuesta y será válido.

Comment: @DanielVorph :) no lo quise decir, pero tenes toda la razón.

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que al definir algo como virtual dejas la posibilidad de sobreescribir la funcionalidad

[virtual (Referencia de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/9fkccyh4.aspx)

esa capacidad es la que aprovecha `entity framework` para actuar de intermediario he inyectar su implementacion, de esta forma puede agregar capacidad de `lazy load` en las relaciones. Sino defines como virtual la propiedad EF no podra interponerse con lo cual el proxy lazy no se inyecta en la entidad.

El definir un List<> o una entidad depende de la navegacion que quieras obtener, esta claro que al ser una lista sera una relacion uno a muchos. Analiza el ejemplo

[Configure One-to-Many Relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

veras como se definen ambas propiedades para tener la navegacion completa, pero ambas deben tener el `virtual`

Comment: Esto es una respuesta. Muchas Gracias. @Leandro

Answer (score 0):

La diferencia entre usar o no virtual es que cuando lo especificas, Entity Framework puede cargar entidades relacionadas con lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

Algo que tienes que tener cuidado con los virtual es que son peligrosos para el rendimiento ya que te cargan los datos relacionados SIEMPRE. En mi opinión lo mejor es no declarar una propiedad virtual si crees que en ésta se cargará con mucho volumen de datos.

Por ejemplo, es como si haces un GET() de un clase PAIS "china" para traerte simplemente la descripción y la clase PAIS tiene relacionada una propiedad `IENUMERABLE<PERSONAS>` , si está con virtual te traerá todos los datos de PERSONAS. Viene a construir una select de pais haciendo join con la tabla personas que tiene millones de registros

Comment: eso no es cierto, si defines virtual una propiedad con entity framework no la carga siempre ya que habilitas lazy load, salvo que al definir la query linq uses el Include().

Comment: Eso pensaba yo hasta que lo he visto con mis propios ojos